# Different Object Types but require same logic

Tags: object, types

I have a problem. I am using VSTO C# and using the MailItem object and AppointmentItem object. Currently, I have classes for each of them that are essentially the same. The only difference is the MailItem class uses the MailItem object in its logic and the same goes for the AppointmentItem.

I want to somehow "merge" these classes so I only need to maintain one code.  Here are some options I tried:

- I tried using overload, but it still resulted to two functions, so
  it's more or less the same scenario previously.

  I tried to create a single method with a "dynamic" parameter, but it
  resulted in syntax errors when I use Linq.

  Finally, I tried using var, but to no avail since I need to declare
  it inside an if-else statement and it's scope is stuck there.

Does anyone have any advise if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are times when the language, because of strict typing rules, requires separate implementations of an algorithm. The best that you can do in those cases is announce in your documentation that the design of the algorithm is the same and make sure to maintain that parallelism in future.

However, in the world of refactoring, a common superclass isn't the only way to do this. I strongly recommend the work of Martin Fowler: http://refactoring.com/.

You didn't say what language you were implementing this in, so I will presume it is a statically typed one, and not something like Smalltalk. You might consider a Visitor pattern, but that might be overkill for just two classes. A Delegate pattern or a Proxy pattern could also work.

I found a useful comparison page for Proxy, Facade and Adaptor: http://www.netobjectivestest.com/PatternRepository/index.php?title=AdapterVersusProxyVersusFacadePatternComparison

Comment: Thanks for this, I am using C#.